# how to return the max seqence record

Tags: sql, db2

I've a table that stores the historical data, what i'm trying to do is trying to capture the max seq record. i can do that, but i need to include the tr_type, then i'll use the outupt to join with another table. below is ex of my data

```
CLM_NO  SEQ SUB TR_TYPE
12345   1   1   50
12345   1   2   50
12345   2   1   60
12345   2   2   60
```

i want to return only the last row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use `exists` and correlated subquery

```
SELECT *
FROM T t1
WHERE exists(
    SELECT 1 
    FROM T tt
    GROUP BY tt.CLM_NO
    HAVING MAX(tt.SEQ) = t1.SEQ AND MAX(tt.SUB) = t1.SUB
)
```

---

**EDIT**

You can try to use `ROW_NUMBER` window function.

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CLM_NO ORDER BY TRAN_SEQ DESC,TRAN_SUB DESC) rn
    FROM TBL t1
)t1
where rn = 1
```

Comment: B0000001 1 1 16
B0000001 1 1 16
B0000001 1 1 16
B0000001 2 1 18
B0000001 2 1 18
B0000001 2 1 18
B0000001 3 1 13
B0000001 4 1 16
B0000001 5 1 18     Returning all the rows

Comment: It work in sqlfiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=42f9dfb778f651e4608ccabef279ea56

Comment: SELECT * FROM tbl T
WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 FROM tbl TT
    GROUP BY TT.CLM_NO
    HAVING MAX(TT.CLM_NO)=T.TT.CLM_NO AND MAX(TT.TR_SUB)=T.TR_SUB);

Comment: The issue is on Having condition `MAX(tt.SEQ) = t1.SEQ `instead of `MAX(TT.CLM_NO)=T.CLM_NO`

Comment: You need to compare `MAX` SEQ and SUB

Comment: Sorry that was a type error, i'm comparing max seq and sub 
SELECT * FROM TBL T
WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 FROM TBL TT
    GROUP BY TT.CLM_NO
    HAVING MAX(TT.TRAN_SEQ)=T.TRAN_SEQ AND MAX(TRAN_SUB)=T.TRAN_SUB);

Comment: Yes, just fix, is that work?  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1b5990ff566fbb3d8cfc05660391a0f9

Comment: No, i'm using DB2.

Comment: @sally It should be work, doesn't matter I write another answer for you

Comment: Window function works but it's just too slow, thanks

Comment: If the query slow you can try to create index and look at execute plan

Comment: You can upvote or accpect this answer if that help you :)

Comment: I've used the exists and the correlated subquery. i've used where tt.claim_no=t1.claim_ no, group by tt.claim_no HAVING MAX(tt.SEQ) = t1.SEQ AND MAX(tt.SUB) = t1.SUB. working for me